# Does $$ mean private variable in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Can someone explain to me why AngularJS some times uses $$ instead of $ for variables.  Is used to communicate that the variable should not be directly used?

For example $$state inside of a promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct!

`$$` variables are internal stuff in the workings of Angular (core) and some plugins (ui-router).

It is not recommended to work directly with them, but hey - rules are meant to be broken.

Just be sure to take care when doing so.

Comment: ["Rules are made to be broken... like buildings! Or people!"](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Jinx/Background)